# Formula or code to map cross-quadrilateral to square

Tags: math, image-processing

I'm building an image warping tool. Photoshop's free transform tool not only supports mapping an rectangular image to a quadrilateral, but also supports cross-quadrilaterals. I'm looking for a formula or piece of code which allows mapping between square and cross-quadrilateral. For normal quadrilateral mappings there is a publication by Heckbert (http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2006_fall/www/Papers/proj.pdf) which fits my needs. Any pointers are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Had a closer look at PS transform tool: it turns out the midpoint of the image is always mapped to the intersection point of the cross-quadrilateral. So I think the mapping could be a composition of actually two perspective mappings.

Comment: Do you mean, the approach is to simply split the cross-quadrilateral to 2 triangles and go ahead keeping in mind that their faces are in opposite direction.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. However I'd prefer a single model. I think photoshop models the image as a textured 3d mesh - there is a freeform warp mode with which one can deform the image using spline controls. The mesh has a front and backside: you can deform the image in such a way the backside is facing up. The cross-quadrilateral case above might be a special case- I imagine a surface that is twisted around the midpoint.